# Exponential amount of information in polynomial size? Impossible!

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, succinct-data-structures

I'm reading [A note on succinct representations of graphs](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82692700.pdf) by Papadimitriou and Yannakakis. Let me quote the following paragraph on page 183:

> Formula $F$ has a highly regular structure. It has $|x|$ clauses stating that the input to the computation of $U$ is $x$, and a finite number of other types of clauses reflecting the moves of $U$, repeated in a regular way an exponential number of times (for each possible time-square combination of the computation of $U$ on $x$). In particular, it is very easy to see that, given two $c|x|$-bit integers, the indices of a literal and a clause, it can be determined in polynomial time whether the literal appears in the clause. Let us call $B$ the polynomial-time algorithm computing this literal-clause relation.

Though $B$ is polynomial-time, it's not polynomial-size because it contains an exponential amount of information, i.e., literal-clause pairs.

Then it continues:

> Combining algorithms $A$ and $B$, we obtain an algorithm $C$ which, given two integers with $ck|x|$ bits, determines in polynomial time whether the two nodes are adjacent in the graph $G(F)$, based only on the bits of $x$. For fixed $x$ this algorithm can be rendered as a polynomial-size circuit $C_{G(F)}$ with $2ck|x|$ inputs, which is therefore a succinct representation of $G(F)$. Now, it is easy to see that, given $x$, we can construct $C_{G(F)}$ in polynomial time.

I don't understand how you can pack an exponential amount of information in "a polynomial-size circuit $C_{G(F)}$." Can you explain? This is the hardest part of the paper, or it is wrong.

Comment: By the way, it's not very polite to suggest that a published paper is "wrong" and "impossible!", just because you don't understand it. Of course, some published papers _are_ wrong (or are essentially right but contain mistakes), but this isn't a situation in which it's appropriate to be making accusations.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: But this claim is outrageous: it claims exponentiality can be encoded in polynomiality and therefore NEXP-complete problems exist. You may be comfortable to accept it, but not me! I believe everything is in P; time hierarchy is just a theoretical aside. I'm just explaining; don't argue about beliefs.

Comment: "I believe everything is in P" Then you're provably wrong, because the time hierarchy theorem isn't "just a theoretical aside". I don't think there's anything more to discuss.

Comment: OK, if you think the inputs are "exponentially many," how is it possible to "construct $C_{G(F)}$ in polynomial time" (the last sentence of the last paragraph)?

Comment: In general, "exponentially many" $\neq$ "exponential amount of information". The clue is in the "highly regular structure" of $F$.

Comment: Even if we only assume that there are exponentially many inputs, and not that the amount of information is exponential, the construction phase still needs exponential time, in the worst case.

Comment: Will it have a range or something?

Answer (score 2):

The circuit encodes an exponential amount of information because it has exponentially many possible inputs. Instead of having an exponential-sized array that stores all the information you want, you instead have a polynomial-sized circuit that computes the information you want.

Comment: No. It has nothing to do with the number of inputs. Information is information. In this case there are no patterns and it's impossible to compress information, whether using a circuit or not.

Comment: We're a question and answer site. If you're just interested in lecturing us about how the paper is wrong, this is the wrong place to do it. The "pattern" is the circuit. The text you quote even says that the formula is "highly regular", which already tells you that it's not encoding arbitrary information.

Comment: Yes, the structure is highly regular, but everywhere it appears, it's associated with a different literal-clause pair. We can encode the structure, but not the literal-clause-pair information. Please be clear.